# Create a service bus subscription in durable functions

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-durable-functions

Is it possible to create a service bus subscription and register a message handler?
I'm a new to durable functions and quite concerned because of [orchestrator code constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-checkpointing-and-replay#orchestrator-code-constraints), especially with this:

> Orchestrator code must never initiate any async operation except by
>   using the DurableOrchestrationContext API

Am I right that it will be impossible to register service bus message handler because it begins a new thread to receive messages and it is awaited on every time a new message is received?

Please notice that it's not a question about the service bus trigger. Actually this orchestration function should be triggered by service bus message in the queue but it also should perform a subscription to another service bus topic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Such a message handler would be a long running function app which wouldn't work on the consumption tier.

***But*** you can still achieve what you are trying.

Instead of a HTTP Starter function which starts an orchestration can actually be triggered by a service bus message too. Its like any other function.

And if your use case entails waiting for another message, you could use the [external events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-external-events) which your orchestration can wait for and another service bus triggered function could raise the external event.